# Getting time If it is not visible or available on Page

Tags: python, date, datetime, selenium-webdriver

I am looking for a way to get the time and date of the post using selenium Python of the publication of the posts.
Problem is that date is not available on the page so I can't locate it using selenium.
Looking for a method to extract it from backend or metadata or any time stamp with the publication of the page or post
Thanks

i searched google for extracting but i found code for locating the on page date. I did't get the code which i am looking for.